# Given two related ratios within a population, derive a third ratio (eg. redheads, non-redheads, and skin cancer)

Tags: self-study, bayesian, biostatistics

If

- People X are N times more likely to have attribute A than non-X
- People X are P percent of the population

then

- What percentage of A's are X?

Example (the numbers are just for illustration).

If

1. A redhead is 3 times more likely to get skin cancer than a non-redhead.
2. Redheads are 7% of the population.

Then

What percentage of skin cancer victims are redheads?

X = Is a Redhead, A = Suffer Skin cancer, N = 3, P = 7

Comment: This looks like self study - what have you attempted so far?

Comment: [Hint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem). The answer is approx 22.5% off the top of my head.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will go through the numerical example.
We are given: $\frac{P(C|R)}{P(C|\lnot R)}=3$ and $P(R)=0.07$. We need to find $P(R|C)$.

Bayes Theorem:

$P(C|R)= \frac{P(R|C)P(C)}{P(R)} \quad P(C|\lnot R)= \frac{P(\lnot R|C)P(C)}{P(\lnot R)} $

Dividing these terms will yield:

$ \frac{P(C|R)}{P(C|\lnot R)}= 3 =\frac{P(R|C)}{P(\lnot R|C)}\frac{P(\lnot R)}{P(R)}=\frac{P(R|C)}{1-P(R|C)}\frac{1-0.07}{0.07}$

Then, you can solve for $P(R|C)$.

Comment: Many thanks for a well worked answer, @Ozan! I've upvoted it, but will have to work through it to confirm before awarding the bounty. I'm broadly familiar with the mathematics you've presented here (which I trust is correct), but rusty. I'll try to finish this within 24 hours and award the bounty. It looks lovely!

Comment: @StephenHosking I hope it helps :)

Comment: Once again, thanks for the solution, for invoking Bayes Theorem (I had thought it was a purely algebraic problem), and for presenting it so elegantly. Bonus awarded!

Comment: Thank you. I am glad that it was useful for you.

Comment: My algebraic manipulation solving for P(R|C) comes up with P(R|C) = A / 1 - A, where A = 1-0.07 / 0.07. Which is 0.18. I'll have to check it a couple of times, and try on other examples fr.